# Chrome font changed after installation of new fonts

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

So I just installed some new fonts on my Ubuntu 16.04 (By opening the respective font file and clicking on Install), and now some of the fonts on my Chrome web pages have changed. For example, the code block on StackExchange sites has a different font now. How can I reset it back to before?

Edit: I need to reset it back, but without uninstalling the new fonts, as I need them for use in a text editor.

Comment: Uninstall the new fonts?

Comment: I need the fonts for use in my text editor.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  What fonts was Chrome using before?  What fonts did you install?

Comment: @xiota I'm afraid I do not remember the details now. What I do remember is that Chrome was using the default fonts before (what you would get if you opened stackoverflow on a fresh Ubuntu installation).
I am still facing a font related issue on my machine, but it is slightly different than what I was facing here. It is described here, and could be helpful for someone facing similar issues - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/49957